# How to get product attributes with values

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, simple-product

How can I get all attributes of product with its values?
I mean attributes like size, color, gender and like that, but not availablity, quantity or sku. I need to use them for filters, how can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

you have write on block class file

```
<?php
namespace Pradip\Magegig\Block;
class Products extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(3); 
        return $collection;
    }
}
?>
```

in Phtml file you will getting all attribute along with product

```
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());     
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: It is not what I ask. Also my ask for magento 1.9 - not 2.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [link](https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-get-product-attribute/).
Which have all the answer of your question.

Thanks

Comment: There no answer for my question.

Comment: Means I am not getting you.